# How to make customized ErrorDecoder and @ExceptionHandler work together in spring cloud

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I have a spring cloud service called "hr", and a api gateway service using Feign as client to call the hr service. If there's any exceptions occurred in the hr service, it will return a json message which type is `ResponseEntity<ServiceException>`. The `ServiceException` is like :

```
public class ServiceException extends Exception {

    private String errorCode;
    // constructors omitted
}
```

In the api gateway service, I customized the `feign.codec.ErrorDecoder` like:

```
@Service
public class SpringWebClientErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {

    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(response.body().asInputStream(), ServiceException.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.info("Failed to process response body");
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to process response body.", e);
        }
    }

}
```

It works fine to get the ServiceException, and I can get the error message something like:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1468158273181,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "ServiceException",
  "message": "sn should not be empty",
  "path": "/employee"
}
```

I want to change the format of the error message and at least add the `errorCode` field of `ServiceException` class, so I add a `@ControllerAdvice` annotation class to try to handle the exception. But unfortunately,  it doesn't work. I'm it may be because the exception is not thrown by Controller by just from some filters, so the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation doesn't work.

Could anyone give me some advices for case, please.

Comment: `@ControllerAdvice` doesn't work on feign clients.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. So, are there any other ways to handle the case?

Comment: You can customize the ribbon context in code (see docs, I'm out and about).